# How to access Cnosdb when using c++ or the c language?

Tags: c++, cnosdb

How to access Cnosdb when using c++ or the c language? Does cnosdb provide c++/c client ? how can I use c++ or the c access the cnosdb? please provide a detail example/

Comment: There is no "C/C++" language. There is "C" and there is "C++" which are different languages. At stack overflow we also expect a real question concerning C++ code you have already written. And for something specific like cnosdb I think you better look at their documentation first (which admittedly doesn't seem to have a documented api)